# Colcon build gives Qt5quick error

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build [this package](https://github.com/TechmanRobotInc/tmr_ros2) on ROS2. I was getting some errors with tf2_geometry_msgs but I resolved that by editing the CMake file and package.xml. Apart from this, I am getting the following error that I cannot get rid of:

--- stderr: ui_for_debug_and_demo
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt5Quick.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick",
but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Quick" with any
of the following names:

```
Qt5QuickConfig.cmake
qt5quick-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Quick" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5Quick_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"Qt5Quick" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.

I installed Qt5 from multiple sources and even tried giving the cmake path by this command:

export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/gcc_64/lib/cmake

However this error keeps persisting and I am unable to build the packages.
Please help with this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392702/colcon-build-gives-qt5quick-error/) by [ronak_bhanushali_iafsm](https://answers.ros.org/users/91486/ronak_bhanushali_iafsm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-14**:
If you already post in stack overflow please don’t duplicate asking again in this forum.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330777/colcon-build-fails-due-to-qt5-error-installed-qt5-but-still-getting-the-same-er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have Qt5 installed?

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
```

Based on [this post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647035/cmake-prefix-path-doesnt-help-cmake-in-finding-qt5).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0